# Cypress Unexpected End of Input (First test)

Tags: reactjs, testing, next.js, cypress

Trying to setup cypress testing for the first time in a repository (Next.js/React). After trying to write my first test file, no matter its contents, I seem to receive this error.

```
  > Unexpected end of input
```

I still receive this error even with this being the entire contents of my test file as of current:

```
describe('empty spec', () => {
  it('passes', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000');
  });
});
```

Any ideas as it pertains to debugging? Cypress is saying that it prints a stack trace from the issue but nothing useful seems to be returned. Any reason as to why this is the case? I assume I've made an error during setup.